# What is the image ratio of xxhdpi?

Tags: android, image

What is the image ratio of xxhdpi? The answer should be related to: http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-densities.png?

Answer (score 3):

The image ratio for xxhdpi is 3.0

Comment: And, since the question will come up eventually, `-xxxhdpi` would be 4.0.